# Pulling flash player content from http server

Tags: flash, http

When a flash player is being hosted on https server, can I pull content to play on it from an http server. Would this work or give a mixed content warning or some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problems.

If the content is stored in different domains make sure that all crossdomain policy files are correctly configured and accessible.

For more information:
[Crossdomain policy files and security](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html)

Answer (score 0):

Pulling over a http-connection works fine. What does not work is pulling over https when you have encoded chararacters in the path, see https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-5580. Adobe does not care about this issue.